# Difference between BPM and App. workflow?

Tags: business-process-management

I know there is a lot of talk about BPM these days and I am conscious that some may see it to be a craze rather than a fundamentally important piece of software.

As someone from what most would call 'The Business', I have been doing my best to learn about BPM to ensure we continue to make decisions that not only make sense to the business, but IT as well.

I have noticed while reading that mention is made to application workflow when sometimes discussing BPM. I hadn't given this much thought until recently.

Therefore, what is the difference? When would you use one and not the other?

Comment: Could I asked this differently? What information would you have needed to give an answer?

Comment: Im not sure I understand the "application workflow" part. Like "BPM is just the workflow of an application"?

Comment: Thats the problem I am having! Could it be that when I hear application workflow they are referring to the method that you employ it? either internally or with an external application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BPM is about the process and improving it, which takes into account users and potentially more than one application,e.g. an ERP system may have more than one application to it, though there may be other uses of the term.  Note that the process could be viewed without what applications or technologies are used.

Application workflow is how an application is used to go from a to b.  Here it is a specific set of code that is used and what happens over the course of an application getting from a to b.  In this case, the application is front and center rather than the process.

Does that provide an answer?  Another way to think of it is that multiple application workflows can make up a system which is used in a process that can have BPM applied to it.

Answer (score 2):

Late to the game, but workflow is to database as BPMS is to DBMS. (Convenient how the letters line up, huh?)

IOW, BPM(S) is traditionally meant to refer to a particular framework/application that allows you to manage business processes: defining them, storing them, versioning them, measuring them, etc. This is similar to how a DBMS manages databases.

Now, a workflow is a definition, much like a database is a definition. In the former case, it is a definition of operations/work (Fufill Order), steps thereof (Send Invoice) and rules/constraints on the work (If no stock, send notice). In the latter, similar case, it is a definition of data structure (CREATE TABLE) and constraints (InvoiceTotal must be > $0.00).

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a potentially confusing subject, particular as some development environments use a type of process flow model to generate user facing applications (I'm thinking about Outsystems here, for example).

But, for me, the distinction is crystal clear. Application workflow, as people talk about it, refers to a user's path through an application, i.e. the pages they complete/visit, the data they enter, etc. on their way to completing a transaction of some sort. Application orkflow is a poor term for this though, I think application flow would be more meaningful.

BPM on other hand, is about modelling and executing a workflow process. By workflow, in this context, I mean a series of discrete steps (or tasks) that have to be completed (either programmatically or via human interaction) in a certain order to complete a process. These tasks can be implemented as individual application modules (each with their own "application workflow", see above). The job of the workflow engine is to make sure that these separate steps are assigned to the right people (of groups of people) in the right sequence, and that overall the process completes in an orderly way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a clear answer to this at all. These are words, as opposed to theoretical concepts. If you add the word "checklist" into the mix - that just turns out to be a linear version of a process (but you can have conditionals in checklists - making them a workflow).

I am not sure how to help in reframing this question, but it's almost as if no answer can ever be possible. My own thoughts are at https://tallyfy.com/improving-efficiency-workflow-vs-business-process-management/